# Strategy for messages that must be delivered in order in Rebus

Tags: rebus

I'm using Rebus SQLTransport with XML serialized messages for integration with SQL Server. Messages represent changes done in SQL Server. Because of that the order of message delivery is essential.

It is because for example message1 may contain object that is referenced (by id) in message2. Another example is that message1 may contain remove request of some object that is required to accept new object from message2.

Aggregating messages into one message would be quite complicated because messages are generated by triggers.

Having message idempotence and one worker I guess that would work except the fact that won't work if error happens and message will be moved to error queue. The error is quite possible to happen because of validation or business logic exception. Because of that I believe only human can fix the problem with message and until that time other messages should not be delivered. So I wanted to ask for advice what would be best to do in that situation. As far as I saw retry number cannot be set to infinity so should I stop the service inside of handler until problem is solved by human?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's important that the messages are processed in order without any "holes", I suggest you assign a sequence number to each message.

This way, if the endpoint gets a message whose sequence number is greater than the expected sequence number it can throw an exception, thus preventing out-of-order messages to be processed.

I would only do this if errors are uncommon though, and only if the message volume is fairly small.

If in-order processing is required, a much better design would be to use another message processing library that supports a *pull* model, which I think would fit your scenario much better than Rebus' *push* model.

Comment: Thank you for another great answer :) Tell me please, where previous sequence numer should be kept? In database, static field? When error occurs would ReturnToSourceQueue tool put my messages back before messages existing in source queue (so messages from error queue would be processed first?)

Comment: First approach should be great in my case, I'm curious though, what do you mean by pull model? How that would be different from Rebus pulling messages from queue or from your Timer pulling from ServiceBroker? (I see messages as the only way to know what changed in database without full table scan, do you?)

Comment: To generate sequence numbers, I'd probably see if [SQL Server's sequence number generators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) could help - then you could grab a number when the trigger fires and assign the number to the message

Comment: By "pull model", I mean: Not using a [FIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO) message queue, instead "send" messages by appending them to a (ordered) stream from which consumers can read. Don't know what the "official" name is for this approach, it goes by many names - "pull", "consumer-driven"/"client-driven" subscribers, + probably many more :)

Comment: I didn't know SQL Server have sequence numer generator, cool :) How should I store numer of previous message in Rebus endpoint to compare it with the incoming one? in static field?

Comment: Also could you advice please, is it possible to place messages from error queue back to source queue BEFORE messages existing in source queue in order to not couse more sequence errors?

Comment: I guess not because there is seq column in sql transport. in msmq it will be similar. so I guess the only way is to stop producer and let all mesages go to error queue. Also, I will need to create ReturnToSourceQueue tool for sql.

Comment: Rebus' SQL transport actually has a feature that _almost_ supports what you're after: Message priority! It's not documented anywhere, but when Rebus' SQL transport receives a message, it [gets messages ordered by priority](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/src/Rebus/Transports/Sql/SqlServerMessageQueue.cs#L207) - only thing is that by default, the priority column in the RebusMessages table is a `tinyint` (i.e. can contain value in the [0;255] range)

Comment: but, as I see it, there's no reason why the priority column could not be a bigint (~ long in C#) which would allow you to attach a priority header to each message, where the value would be the sequence number value for that message

Comment: wow, this is just great :D in order to not modify rebus I could even use separate header for sequence number (or actually why not use already existing seq column aka messageId itself?) and priority only for returning message to source queue

Comment: tell me please how should I store sequence number of previous message in Rebus endpoint to compare it with the incoming one? in static field? (assuming I have only one worker ofc)

Comment: you could read it from somewhere when the application starts up, and then remember to update it after having processed each (successfully delivered) message

Comment: I am facing the same problem and I'm trying to find a good  message processing library that supports a pull model as you mentioned. Got any recommendations for .net 4.6.1 ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the "log-based" type of message broker, e.g. like Kafka. If you're interested in an approachable way to use Kafka, you could take a look at [Topos](https://github.com/mookid8000/Topos), which is kinda like "a Rebus for log-based brokers like Kafka", which I am playing around with at the moment

Comment: @mookid8000 I came here looking for this SQL Server Transport Priority, but the link you provided is not working. I guess it can be used through a message's header when queueing a message, but can't find the optional header's list... Please can you point me in any direction? Thanks

Comment: Check out [this test case](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus.SqlServer/blob/master/Rebus.SqlServer.Tests/Transport/TestMessagePriority.cs) – it sends a bunch of messages with the priority header set, and then it receives them and verifies that they were received in order by priority.